# Приостановка цикла нажатием кнопки

Tags: c#

На форме имеется две кнопки.

По нажатию первой запускается цикл, который может работать довольно большой промежуток времени. Нажатие второй должно приостановить цикл.

Каким образом можно добиться такого поведения? Ведь цикл работает в обработчике первой кнопки.

Как же циклу дать знать, что была нажата кнопка "Стоп"?

Вот пример кода:

```
public void b1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
   {
      ...
   }
}

public void b2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ???
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для начала: так не пойдёт.

Ваш цикл в обработчике события блокирует UI, и не даёт шанса отработать событиям от мыши. Кроме того, и всё приложение будет выглядеть зависшим.

Современный метод выполнения фоновых заданий с приостановкой — использование TPL: вам нужен `Task` и `CancellationToken`.

```
CancellationTokenSource cts;

public async void b1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cts != null)
        return;
    using (cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
        await Calculate(cts.Token);
    cts = null;
}

public void b2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cts != null)
        cts.Cancel();
}

Task Calculate(CancellationToken ct)
{
    return Task.Run(() => CalculateImpl(ct), ct);
}

void CalculateImpl(CancellationToken ct)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
    {
        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            return;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: См. первый коммент к первому ответу

Comment: @master_clown: `Task.Run` запустит задание в отдельном потоке, если вы об этом.

Comment: Я бы `Calculate` заинлайнил в `b1`, а то на простую вещь столько методов — глаза разбегаются.

Comment: @Athari: В production-коде `Calculate` было бы публичным фасадом какого-нибудь модельного класса. Я из этих соображений. (А логика `b1` была бы в VM.)

Comment: @VladD Рано думать про подобную архитектуру, если код торчит к хэндлере клика кнопки в code-behind...

Comment: @Athari: Ну это да :-) [Magic button](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_pushbutton).

Comment: Ещё: b1, b2, b2 => ObjectDisposedException.

Comment: @Athari click, click, boom! это же пример для демонстрации идеи, а не продакшн код.

Comment: И ещё: `Task.Run(() => CalculateImpl(ct), ` **`ct`** `)`

Comment: Логика ясна, спасибо. Кстати, а что это за оператор =>?

Comment: @master_clown: Это лямбда-функция. Как в JS :-)

Comment: @VladD, о, ясно. Я больше с плюсами знаком, чем с Java. Там чуточку другой синтаксис

Comment: @Athari: О, а вот это правильно. Фенкс! Сейчас подправлю.

Answer (score 4):

Я бы рекомендовал использовать отдельный поток для длительной задачи, чтобы не тормозить поток UI. В данном случае вполне подойдет класс [`BackgroundWorker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker):

```
private BackgroundWorker bw;

public void b1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bw = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerSupportsCancellation = true };
    bw.DoWork += (obj, args) =>
         {
             BackgroundWorker lbw = (BackgroundWorker)obj;
             for (int i = 0; i < 1000000 && !lbw.CancellationPending; ++i)
             {
                ...
             }
         };
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}

public void b2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (bw != null && bw.IsBusy && !bw.CancellationPending)
        bw.CancelAsync();
}
```

Comment: А `if (bw.CancellationPending)`?

Comment: @Athari спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой вариант:

- Заведите булево поле — флаг, нужно ли продолжать выполнение операции.
- Выполняйте цикл не в UI потоке (там ничего долго выполняющегося быть не должно). К контролам обращайтесь через `Control.Invoke`.
- По нажатию на кнопку Стоп задавайте флагу значение остановки.
- Булево поле должно быть `volatile`, иначе компилятор может "оптимизировать" код и избавиться от "избыточной" проверки (ведь внутри цикла значение переменной не меняется).

Примерно так:

```
private volatile bool _isRunning;

private void buttonStart_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(() => {
        _isRunning = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            Invoke((Action)(() => Text = i.ToString()));
            if (!_isRunning)
                break;
        }
    });
}

private void buttonStop_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _isRunning = false;
}
```

Comment: Хм. А вы уверены в семантике `volatile`?

Comment: @VladD Э... А в чём именно сомнения? Вроде, это самый топорный дедовский способ (только припудренный `Task.Run`).

Comment: Ну, в том, что можно использовать одну и ту же переменную в другом потоке без `lock`'а? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/16/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-three.aspx

Comment: И http://joeduffyblog.com/2010/12/04/sayonara-volatile/

Comment: @VladD В этом коде не возникает проблемы из-за того, что значение булевой переменной неактуальное. Хоть цикл остановится через одну итерацию, хоть через десять, хоть через пятьдесят — с точки зрения пользователя это не будет иметь значения. Использовать volatile для многопоточного доступа — не самая лучшая затея в общем случае, но в данном конкретном случае всё работает корректно. Невоспринимаемую на глаз задержку при нажатии на "Стоп" я не считаю ошибкой.

Comment: @VladD Да, честное решение через CancellationToken — более корректное и, наверное, приучает писать правильно, но оно заметно более многословно. Плюс ваш код не отражает всей многословности: нужно, как минимум, добавить проверку, что операция выполняется, и это состояние хранить (`cts = null`?). Как по мне, слишком много плясок и потенциальных ошибок ради "правильного" решения.

Comment: Пожалуй, вы правы. Там ещё танцы вокруг cts должны быть, и в общем получается типичная асинхронная бизнес-логика со всеми её прелестями. В качестве скрытого достоинства моего решения, там ещё можно в начале `b1` заблокировать, а в конце снова разблокировать кнопку №1.

Comment: @VladD Ну, это добавить несложно: `async buttonStart_Click`, `await` перед `Task.Run` и изменение свойства с двух сторон. Ну, `try`/`finally` по вкусу. :)

Answer (score 0):

Можно завести логическое поле, которое проверять на каждой итерации цикла в методе `b1` и устанавливать в методе `b2`.

Примерно так:

```
private volatile bool _stop_cycle;   

public void b1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _stop_cycle = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000 && !_stop_cycle; ++i)
    {
         ...
    }
}

public void b2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     _stop_cycle = true;
}
```

[Здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/x13ttww7.aspx) разбирается пример работы с переменными, доступными из разных потоков, на более простом примере с циклом `while`.

Comment: Я вот недавно с .NET начал работать. Не хотел этим способом пользоваться, потому что мне кажется, что все эти проги выполняются в одном потоке, поэтому компьютер, занятый исполнением цикла, событие СТОП просто не заметит. Надеюсь, я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Да, это так. Чтобы код работал, необходимо, чтобы метод `b2` мог получить управление во время работы метода `b1`. Выше предложили более качественные варианты решения этой проблемы.